# Macports, variants, excessive dependencies

Tags: dependencies, sdl-2, macports

I have written a little graphics library for my students and C++. Since Apple has removed the Carbon interface, I am trying to revive its Mac implementation using SDL. So far so good, until I wanted to implement the use of images. I installed libsdl2_image, and it installed an absolute PIGLOAD of dependencies, among them perl and two versions of Python! Took numerous minutes to install.  And to make matters worse, a note printed at the end that some of the dependencies installed are under GPL. I can't live with that.

Question #1: is there any command in Macports that will completely undo the last install, with all dependencies installed at that time?

Question #2: I'm trying to understand variants, because it looks like this is something that I need.

```
% port variants libsdl2_image
libsdl2_image has the variants:
   jxl: Enable JPEG XL support (experimental)
   universal: Build for multiple architectures
```

However, its own message concerning GPL dependencies states:

```
To include all nonfree, GPLed and LGPL code use variant +nonfree.
To remove nonfree and GPLed code leaving only LGPL code remove the +gpl2
variant.
```

So it would seem that variants exist that are recognized but not listed by the **port variants** command. How deep does this go? How many others might there be? Obviously, this massive install happened because the package is supporting every conceivable format of image. But really I would be satisfied with png (jpeg would be nice), a small subset of that. If I could find a variant that would come close to doing what I want, and get rid of a lot of those other dependencies, I sure would like to use it.

Question #3: After the fact, will this command delete any of those GPL-based dependencies that were brought in by mistake? I want them GONE from my system.

```
sudo port install libsdl2_image -gpl2 -nonfree
```